# How to make pagination search with SearchAfter() using .NET NEST API

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch

I work on a small .NET 6 API project with elastic search using Nest package. I have an API controller that is supposed to send a specific number of results ex: 10 with every request with elasticSerach.SearchAfter() method.
I search for a code example to know how to use it but I didn't find a clear example for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 1):

Use scroll api:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/scrolling-documents.html

First call, will be valable 10m (elastic take a snapshop for X minutes, and you can use it to scroll (=paginate). This point is very important. The max duration es can store the snapshot is 1d (1 day, i thinck it should be enough for your case).

```
var searchResponse = Client.Search<Project>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        // your query
    )
    .Size(10)
    .Scroll("10m") 
);
```

And after, for each "SearchAfter", to get the next 10 elements

```
searchResponse = Client.Scroll<Project>("10m", searchResponse.ScrollId);
```

If you have large amount of data, or need more feature, take a look at search_after (better, but more complex):
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html#search-after

Comment: Not clear enough! it gets the first element then always return the second element. Here is the controller: 

public async Task<IActionResult> SearchForProductsAsync(string keyword)
{
   var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Product>(s => s
 .Query(q =>
q.QueryString(d =>
     d.Query('*' + keyword + '*')))
   .Size(1)
   .Scroll("10m"));
      if (searchResponse.Documents.Any()) 
      {
        searchResponse = _elasticClient.Scroll<Product>("10m", searchResponse.ScrollId);
        return Ok(searchResponse.Documents.ToList());
      }
      return NotFound();
}

Comment: I type on notepad, could have some syntax error, use a static if share between users.

Comment: ISearchResponse<Product> searchResponse == null;
public async Task<IActionResult> SearchForProductsAsync(string keyword) {
       if (searchResponse == null) {
             searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Product>(s => s.Query(q => q.QueryString(d => d.Query('' + keyword + ''))).Size(1).Scroll("10m"));
          }
    else {
         searchResponse = _elasticClient.Scroll<Product>("10m", searchResponse.ScrollId);
            }
        if (searchResponse.Documents.Any())
             return Ok(searchResponse.Documents.ToList();
         return NotFound();
        }

Comment: Doesn't work,  searchresponse variable reset to null with every request and  HTTP body always contains the first product in elastic search

Comment: Set is as static then.  Check the first link you will see you will be able tro retrieve all the documents. You need to hold the scrollId (or searchReponse wathever) on server side. Each time the controller is call, get next scroll and catch the new scrollid (or keep es response on server). Are you familier with mvc / asp model controller pattern?

Comment: Yes, I am. But I'm a little confused about static vars. if I set it as static var that makes it shared between all users who request to my server, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, if you want custom result for each users, you need to use sessions.